# Netty RtspEncoder/Decoder issue

Tags: java, netty, rtsp

To develop RtspClient(just message transaction, not playing video), I thought that I will use Netty, and I have created the classes as follow,(rtsp is creating toooo much problem to me, I don't know, is this because lag of knowledge? any-how...),

TestRtspClient.java

```
    public class TestRtspClient {

    private final String host;
    private final int port;

    public TestRtspClient(String host, int port) {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;       
    }

    public void start() throws Exception {

        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        try {

            Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();

            bootstrap.group(group);
            bootstrap.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
            bootstrap.handler(new TestRtspClientInitializer());

            Channel channel = bootstrap.connect(host, port).sync().channel();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            //DESCRIBE rtsp://192.168.1.26:8554/nature.ts RTSP/1.0\r\nCSeq: 3\r\n\r\n
            while(true) {
                channel.write(br.readLine() + "\r\n");
                channel.flush();
            }

        } finally {
            group.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new TestRtspClient("192.168.1.26", 8554).start();
    }   
}
```

and here is TestRtspClientInitializer.java

```
    public class TestRtspClientInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {

        ChannelPipeline pipe = ch.pipeline();

//      pipe.addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
//      pipe.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder());
//      pipe.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());

//      pipe.addLast("encoder", new RtspRequestEncoder());
//      pipe.addLast("decoder", new RtspResponseDecoder());

        pipe.addLast("encoder", new HttpRequestEncoder());
        pipe.addLast("decoder", new HttpResponseDecoder());

        pipe.addLast("handler", new TestRtspClientHandler());
    }
}
```

and here is TestRtspClientHandler.java

```
public class TestRtspClientHandler extends ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter<HttpObject> {

      @Override
      public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String msg) throws Exception {
              if(msg instanceof HttpResponse) {
                 System.out.println("Rtsp Response"); 
              } else if(msg instanceof HttpRequest) {
                 System.out.println("Rtsp Request"); 
              } else {
                 System.err.println("not supported format");
              }
       }

}
```

and I am using Live555MediaServer as RtspServer and Netty 4.0.0.CR3. When I am using DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder with stringdecoder and encoder its working fine, but If I use RtspRequest/Response encoder/decoder I am getting following warning, and no msg will be sent to L555.(also same with HttpReq/Resp encoder and decoder)

passing this as commandline arg in eclipse

> DESCRIBE rtsp://192.168.1.26:8554/nature.ts RTSP/1.0\r\nCSeq: 3\r\n
>
> Mar 25, 2014 6:45:28 PM
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$ByteHeadHandler flush WARNING:
>   Discarded 1 outbound message(s) that reached at the head of the
>   pipeline. Please check your pipeline configuration.

Help me to fix this issue, and also explain me in-brief what is wrong in this code modules.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please upgrade to the latest Netty 4.0.x version.

Because you specified `<String>` when you extend `ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter` in your `TestRtspClientHandler`, it will only receive a message whose type is `String`, which is not the case.  You have to use `HttpObject` instead of `String`.

Comment: only that change is enough to overcome that prob?, because, before asking question here i have tried to use HttpObject and also while trying Rtsp, i have used RtspObjectEnc/Dec, but still facing same prob.. I think I am doing some other mistake also. can u please clerify me?

Comment: And as you told, I have updated netty with netty-all-4.0.17.final.jar, now error is not coming and also no output. In Live555 side, debug message says that the connection is established, but request is not received. help me to solve this.

Comment: I am repeating that, If i am using <String> and in pipeline if I am using StringEncoder/Decoder I am able to get the response, but instead of using String Encoder/Decoder, I want to use Rtsp for that only i am getting problem

Comment: That's not really expected.  Would you mind if I ask you to file an issue? - https://github.com/netty/netty/issues

Comment: I have posted the same question in the given link. But no response till now.

Comment: till now no response... help me to fix this trustin.